# Create array out of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array out of two arrays. I tried to use array_merge but it doesn't work.

With the first array, I pull all IDS of custom posts.

```
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
        'fields'          => 'id',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type' => 'items'
    ));
    
    $ids = array();
    
    foreach($all_posts as $a){
        $id[] = array("id"=>$a->ID); 
    }
```

With second array I get only items assigned to that page:

```
    $items = get_field('items');
       
       $assigned_items= array();
    
        foreach($items as $p){ 
           $id = $p["select_item"][0]->ID;
           $price= $p["price"];
           $live = $p["live"];

        $assigned_items[]=array("id"=>$id, "price"=>$available, "live"=>$live);

       }
```

$price and $live variables are boolean.

Now I need to create an array out of these two. As the first array pulls all items, I need to merge with id in the second array. $price and $live could be one true one false.

I need to create an array with all ids from $ids array and add $price and $live elements to it from the second array if the ids are the same. If id doesn't exist in the second array, both price and live are false in the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this, I also made some improvement to your code and check if there is any post or item before loop (to avoiding warning from php) also better error handling.

```
<?php

$ids = $assigned_items = $merged = array();
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
    'fields'          => 'id',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'po|st_type'      => 'items'
));
if($all_posts) { 
    foreach($all_posts as $a){
        // $id[] = array("id"=>$a->ID);
        $merged[$a->ID]["id"] =  $a->ID;
    }
    $items = get_field('items');
    if($items) {
        foreach($items as $p){ 
            $id = $p["select_item"][0]->ID;
            $price= $p["price"];
            $live = $p["live"];
            // $assigned_items[]=array("id"=>$id, "price"=>$available, "live"=>$live);
            $merged[$id]["price"] =  $price;
            $merged[$id]["live"] =  $live;
        } else {
            // no item ...
        }
    }
} else {
    // no post ...
}
```

Comment: the only thing that doesn't work is the answer is that id  in all_post that doesn't exist in the second array doesn't have price and live false [5503]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5503)
    ["price"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["live"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [5502]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5502)
  }

Comment: @dzc Is there multiple Items per each post or  / 1 item per post ?

Comment: multiple, but I solved it. Your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

if you assign your second iteration object, to the key in the array, you can easily merge them.

```
$assigned_items[$p["select_item"][0]->ID] = ['id' => $id, 'price' => $available, 'live' => $live];
```

Now you could join them, by accessing the assigned items by the id. Combining the arrays with the `+` operator.

```
foreach ($all_posts as $post) {
    $combined = (array) $post + $assigned_items[$poost->ID] ?? [];
}
```

This would also eliminate you, from doing the `$ids` iteration.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I dump $combined I get only IDS. I am trying to form an array that has all values from the first array and pickup price and live values from the second for the same id. if id from first array doesn't exist in the second, price and live will be false. The reason why I am iterating first as it is wp object and I am taking only ID out of it.

Comment: I assumed that was an array, not that experienced with wp. Updated my answer, but saying you only get id's out is fairly vague, what are you exactly getting? Because i'm not looping the ids, i'm looping the $all_posts. Combining post and assigned items should give the right result. Therefor this code should make an error trying to add object and an array.

Comment: even if work it can be wrong,  `$post->iD` is not in the key of iteration as same as items!

Comment: used the wrong key for assigning, but still combining two arrays are fairly straightforward in PHP and should be a process that doesnt take 40 lines.